# Take ownership of existing k8s resources on first helm install

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm migrating from a barebones k8s setup composed of services, configmaps & deployment to helm.

Upon first `helm install` I encounter the following error:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. 
Unable to continue with install: 
Service "myservice" in namespace "mynamespace" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "myreleasename"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "mynamespace"
```

This error is expected, since indeed, the entire set of k8s resources are identical with the ones that are already deployed.
Is there a way to make helm take ownership of the existing resources?

I would like to avoid deploying a parallel stack, because then I need to wait until all clients migrate to the new service name, before I can complete the migration.